# Android GridView, how to make image items have the same width and height

Tags: android, gridview

I'm implementing a GridView which lists images, similar to a thumbnail, below is my getView method in the adapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    MyData theData=datas.get(pos);
    String src=theData.getSrc();
    imageView.setTag(src);
    Drawable dr = imgFetcher.loadImage(this, imageView);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
    return imageView;
}
```

As you may notice, **imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85)** hard code the image width and height, but I don't want to hard code it, instead, I want to make the width fill parent and the height be the same as the width. Anyone knows how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many columns you have in you GridView, and you have the GridView object(Let's call it "gv"), you can do as this:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, gv.getWidth()/columnNumber));
```